# how to change the title value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

**I Try The Code But it doesnot working?**

```
     <html>

       <head>

       <script>

    document.getElementbyId("title1").value="MyTitle";

         </script>

     <title id="title1"> </title>

      </head>

       <body>

        </body>

      </html>
```

Is that any methods are available in javascript?

Comment: Put the script block as a last child of body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `document.title` See the MDN Docs for [`document.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title id="title1"></title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
<script>
  document.title = "MyTitle";
</script>

</html>
```

2. If you are using DOM manipulation, do it after the element is loaded.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title id="title1"></title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
<script>
  document.getElementbyId("title1").value = "MyTitle";
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.title`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title id="title1"> </title>
  <!-- note `<script>` element after `<title>` element -->
  <script>
    document.title = "MyTitle";
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```